# HighSlide does not pop up

Tags: javascript, popup, imageflow

I have ImageFlow and Highslide working on my site, but do not understand why when the image is clicked it just hangs in perpetual loading?

The url to my website is:

http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/Main_New7.html

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It starts with:

```
Main_New7.html:17Uncaught ReferenceError: Asset is not defined
Main_New7.html:56Uncaught ReferenceError: MM_preloadImages is not defined
GET http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/highslide/graphics/outlines/drop-shadow.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/highslide/graphics/zoomout.cur 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/highslide/graphics/outlines/rounded-white.png 404 (Not Found)
```

What happens if you use the full path to the image in the longdesc instead of "img/allhallowseve.jpg"

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your above image links... I just needed to make another folder called highslide and place the graphics folder in that.

Comment: How come the slider sits ontop of the pop up?

Comment: #CGI-Archive_navigation has a z-index of 10000 and your popup only has a z-index of 1000, if you increase the z-index of highslide-container to 10001 it will be larger and on top.

Comment: Thanks... took some time, but I found all the problem CSS... changed them all to 900 numbers instead

Answer (score 0):

I get a 404 File not found, when I click the first image, `GET http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/highslide/graphics/outlines/rounded-white.png 404 (Not Found)`

You may need to fix those urls.